# How to Make a Sortable item Bring a div above when you drag it up with jquery?

Tags: jquery, z-index, jquery-ui-sortable

I want a list

Item 1 up
Item 2 up

that will be shortable and when you drag item 2 to make the green div come above the red div. meaning is z-index will be higher!

is my link to see it working so far..
http://jsfiddle.net/2vgRY/

Thanks guys in advance!

EDIT:

just one last thing! when i place a 3rd item and place it above the 2nd i want the first one to still be on the top then the 3rd, then the 2nd.. http://jsfiddle.net/2vgRY/3/

its like a sorting thing , you draf item 3 up then div 3 comes up, you drag item 2 bellow item 1 then div 1 is first then div 2 bellow it then div 3 last ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly, you can use jQuery UI sortable() [start event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#event-start):

See this working [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/2vgRY/1/)!

**JQUERY**

```
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
        start: function(event, ui) {
            // clear z-index
            $('span[class^="target_"]').css({
                "z-index" : '0'
            });

            // bring up the target
            var item = ui.item.attr('class').split(' ')[0];
            $('.' + item.replace("item", "target")).css({
                "z-index" : 10000
            });
        },
    });

    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="item_1 ui-state-default">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1 up
  </li>
  <li class="item_2 ui-state-default">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2 up
  </li>
</ul>
<span class="target_1" style="background:red;padding:30px; position:absolute; float:left;">1</span>
<span class="target_2" style="background:green; padding:30px; margin-left:10px; position:absolute; float:left;">2</span>
```

**Note** that I've added the class `item_x` and the class `target_x` to allow the elements identification.

Comment: May i say I LOVE YOU!:D Thanks its perfect!

Comment: i placed a 3rd item and the sortening is not correct now.. http://jsfiddle.net/2vgRY/3/

Comment: because i place item 3 between item 1 and 2 and the div 3 is above the other divs! and it should be between the other two divs!

Comment: @user1035890, I'm going to take a look! please wait a bit!

Comment: @user1035890, Works just fine, the problem was the `background-color` and `margin-left` that was the same for `target_2` and `target_3`, see this Updated [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/2vgRY/4/)! Being the same you don't realize the change! But it is being done!

Comment: ok! :) thanks lastly.. if the sortable list says. item 1 , item 2, item 3 then i wanted the divs to show the same... div 1(red)above,div 2 (green) undr, div 3(yellow) bellow the others! if i drag item 2 in between item 1 and item 3 the div of item 2 still appears above all menwhile its in the middle in the list above!

Comment: That's already off topic, as stated on the faqs, But, I'll make does adjustments and give you a new Fiddle Example! Give me some minutes!

Comment: Oh! Sorry then, surely My fault :) i appreciate your help sir.

Comment: There you have it, I believe it's what you requested! [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/2vgRY/8/). What this last fiddle does is to use the stop() to call a re-order of the target elements.